# Handle elements that occasionally spill outside of main grid

Tags: bourbon, neat, grid-system

I would like to use Neat 2.0 but I'm wondering what would be the correct approach to handle elements that occasionally spill outside of the main 12 column grid.

I see designs that do this from time to time, either by spilling out just a little or the full width.

Comment: Do you mean that you might want a child element to span across more columns than the parent?

Comment: Conceptually I wasn't understanding but I now figure the general idea would be to have multiple sections (each defining their own grid) then when you want to expand wider, use either a full width div or set a new grid. 
As opposed to putting everything completely inside a master grid and somehow breaking out of it.

Comment: well, I'm having a little trouble getting it perfect, but here's one option to play around with: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWrVWR  I havn't spent too much time with Neat since they moved to 2.0.  I'm not sure why the child div isn't centered correctly.

Comment: I mean, you can absolutely set different grid widths to different containers or create custom grid settings for your project.